# Equivalent conditions of a proper continuous action by a discrete group on a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

I want to prove the following result:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group acting continuously on a topological manifold $M$. Then, the action of $\Gamma$ on $M$ is proper if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. For each $p \in M$, there is an open set $p \in U \subseteq M$ such that $g \cdot U \cap U = \emptyset$ for all but finitely many $g \in \Gamma$.
> 2. If $p, p' \in M$ are in distinct orbits (under the action of $\Gamma$), then there are open sets $U, U'$ containing $p, p'$ such that for all $g \in \Gamma$ we have $g \cdot U \cap U' = \emptyset$.

Prior to this, I have already used the following result:

> **Theorem:** Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group and $M$ be a topological manifold. Let $\Gamma$ act continuously on $M$. Then, the action of $\Gamma$ on $M$ is proper if and only if for any $p, p' \in M$ we have open sets $U, U' \subseteq M$ containing $p, p'$ such that $\overline{U}$ and $\overline{U'}$ are compact and the set $\left\lbrace g \in \Gamma | g \cdot U \cap U' \neq \emptyset \right\rbrace$ is finite.

In proving the result I want, first, we assume that the action is proper. Then, point (1) is satisfied due to the theorem. In proving (2), let $g \in \Gamma$ be such that $g \cdot U \cap U' \neq \emptyset$. Then, $g \cdot p \in U'$ (which is a neighbourhood of $p'$). I want to use this to conclude that $p$ and $p'$ are in the same orbit. However, I am unable to get a hint at this!

Similarly, when proving the converse, if $p$ and $p'$ are in distinct orbits, then the set $\left\lbrace g \in \Gamma | g \cdot U \cap U' \neq \emptyset \right\rbrace = \emptyset$ and hence finite. However, if they are in the same orbit, then I know that it is required to use point (1), but again, I fail to see how!

Any suggestions and hints in this direction will be helpful and much appreciated!

Comment: A strategy for proper implies (2) is to use sequences and prove the contrapositive. So suppose for every pair of open sets containing $p$ and $p'$ there exists some $g$ so that $gU \cap U' \neq \varnothing$. Take $V, V'$ precompact sets containing $p$ and $p'$ respectively and study only open sets $U \subseteq V$ and $U' \subseteq V'$. Then you can build a sequence $(g_n x_n)$ with $x_n \rightarrow p$ and $g_n \rightarrow g$. Now use properness/continuity of the action to show that you can refine the sequence so that $g_n \rightarrow g$ and get that $p$ and $p'$ live in the same orbit.

Comment: You've almost got the other direction as well. Take $p, p'$ in the same orbit, so $gp = p'$. Now there exists $U$ precompact so that $|\{r \in \Gamma : rU \cap U \neq \varnothing\}| < \infty.$ Let $U' = gU$. Study $\{r \in \Gamma : rU \cap gU \neq \varnothing\} = \{r \in \Gamma : g(g^{-1}rU \cap U) \neq \varnothing\} = g(\{ g^{-1}r \in \Gamma : g^{-1}rU \cap U \neq \varnothing\} ).$ Notice this set is still finite.